# DidBeginContact in another class

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I whant to handle all my contacts in another class. I do not realy know how to do it, so I am doing it like this:

**HandleContact is sub class of SKNode**

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {

    HandleContact *handleContact = [[HandleContact alloc]
    initWithBodyA:contact.bodyA.node bodyB:contact.bodyB.node
    scene:self];
}
```

**Everything works as aspected**, but i am getting this error:

> Unused variable 'HandleContact'

**So how should I do it in correct way ? (Maybe i should use another type? )**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is a memory leak. Every time a contact is registered, you instantiate a HandleContact class. If you want to have a class to handle your contacts, I suggest you instantiate it at the beginning of your code and keep a reference to it. Some place like `(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view`

The question you need to ask yourself is why do you need a class to handle your contacts? You can call different methods from within `didBeginContact` if you are looking to organize your code.

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision == (CategoryAlpha | CategoryBeta))
        [self myMethod1];
}
```

Comment: I would like to keep it in another file (It should be a big file). How should I instantiate my class and how should i use it ?

Comment: @DFrog - Create an ivar. In your didMoveToView method instantiate your class. Having it referenced with the ivar, you can now use it in your didBeginContact method. Create a class method in your custom class with the parameters you need. Something like -(void)myMethodWithBodyA:(uint32_t)bodyA BodyB:(uint32_t)bodyB